# Post-build event: Копирование результатов сборки в другую папку

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Есть проект с dll, которую после билда постоянно вручную копирую в нужную папку. Для автоматизации попробовал указать Post-build event. Просто dll скопировать легко:

```
copy $(TargetPath) $(SolutionDir)..\..\lib\
```

А как за ней утянуть еще и xml описание? Не силен в bat'анике, надо как то отрезать от `$(TargetPath)` расширение ".dll" или есть другие способы?

Answer (score 3):

- `Visual Studio` сама копирует все сборки (`dll'ки`) и соответствующие им `xml` файлы в выходную папку, если ваш проект на `.NET` имеет на них ссылки (`References`), при этом сложные графы зависимостей резолвятся автоматически. С учетом того, что вы говорите о копировании `xml` файлов, предположительно, с документацией к сборке, то речь видимо идет о некоторой `managed` сборке.

> Таким образом, можно предположить, вы просто неправильно проставили настройки `References` в вашем проекте, поскольку копирование `dll'ок`, необходимых для запуска проекта **должно происходить автоматически.** Файлы с `xml` документацией по сборкам также копируются автоматически.

---

- Если я где-то ошибся в своих предположениях, то могу предложить вам более общее решение. Вместо того, чтобы как-то отрезать от названий файлов расширения и реализовывать некоторую сложную логику в `Post-Build Events`, сделайте примерно следующее:
- Определите множество файлов, которые **всегда** необходимо копировать в папку с собранным приложением (в вашем случае здесь будет дополнительная `dll'ка` и соответствующий ей `xml` файл).
- Отведите для этих файлов специальную папку в вашем проекте. Я в своих проектах использую папки с названиями `data` и `static_data`.

> Семантика этих названий следующая - в `data` хранятся файлы, без которых запуск приложения или тестов невозможен. Это могут быть какие-то входные данные, файлы для тест-кейсов, какие-то `unmanaged` `dll'ки` и т.п. В `static_data` находятся вспомогательные данные, которые просто используются в проекте - например, графические `assets`, скетчи `UI`, важная информация в `pdf'ках`.

- Далее в `Post-Build Events` добавьте следующую команду:

> `xcopy "$(SolutionDir)data\*.*" "$(TargetDir)" /S /E /Y`

- Этим вы гарантируете, что в случае успешной сборки проекта все файлы из `data` будут скопированы в `Output` папку с собранным приложением.

> Есть еще один важный момент, на который стоит обратить внимание - если файлы в папке `data` обновились, то они, естественно, не будут скопированы в `Output` до пересборки проекта, а значит, в некоторый момент времени, несмотря на то, что вы уже обновили файлы, собранное приложение будет работать со старым комплектом файлов. **Это достаточно критично для тестов.**

Comment: Не совсем то что нужно =) У меня есть сферический проект(ы) в вакууме, выход которого (dll и xml) я копирую в определенную папку(lib). На эту папку ссылаются разные солюшены (на dllки в ней). Вот такой процесс деплоя (если его можно так назвать) я бы и хотел записать в пост билд.

Answer (score 2):

Нужны просто немного другие команды в макросе. Вот пример из нашего проекта:
copy /Y "$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).dll" "$(SolutionDir)....\Export\$(TargetName).dll"
copy /Y "$(TargetDir)$(TargetName).dll" "$(SolutionDir)....\Export\$(TargetName).xml"

точно так же можно добавить и pdb